# Looping through arrays to create worksheet in Vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, search

I need some help here. I am trying to check & create new worksheets within a workbook by looping through the Arrays. How would I assign Arr() as an object? Please advise.

```
  Sub update()
    Dim myworksheet As Worksheet
    
    Dim Arr() As Variant

Arr() = Array ("Square", "Circle", "Rectangle", "Hexagon")
icount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Arr())
Z = 0
For k = Z To icount
**Set myworksheet = Worksheets(Arr(Z)) '<---- THIS throws me out of subscript error** 
If Not sheetexists("myworksheet") Then
Worksheets.Add.Name = "myworksheet"
End If
Z = Z + 1
Next k
End Sub

Function sheetexists(shtname As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet
If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtname)
On Error GoTo 0
sheetexists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here. Firs you set:
`icount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Arr())`
Which in this case is 4.
But they array starts at 0, so when you do `For k = Z To icount` you say "from 0 to 4"
But `Worksheets(Arr(4))` doesn't exist, since the array has items 0-3.

Next `If Not sheetexists("myworksheet") Then` looks for a worksheet named "myworksheet", not the variable `myworksheet` that we just assigned.
You probably want `If Not sheetexists(myworksheet.Name) Then` instead.
I'm guessing the same issue is with `Worksheets.Add.Name = "myworksheet"`

Then there's really no need to have two counters, k and z, since k will start at 0 and `next k`will set it + 1.

`Set myworksheet = Worksheets(Arr(Z))` Doesn't really work here however. First you set a worksheet to a variable, and then you check if it exists. But if it doesn't exist, you can't set it.

So if we use a string instead, it should work better:

```
Sub update()
Dim myworksheet As String
Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim k As Long

Arr() = Array("Square", "Circle", "Rectangle", "Hexagon")
For k = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    myworksheet = Arr(k)
    If Not sheetexists(myworksheet) Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = myworksheet
    End If
Next k
End Sub
```

Here's and example of a for each loop as a bonus:

```
Sub update()
Dim k As Variant
For Each k In Array("Square", "Circle", "Rectangle", "Hexagon")
    If Not sheetexists(k) Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = k
    End If
Next k
End Sub

Function sheetexists(shtname As Variant, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet
If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtname)
On Error GoTo 0
sheetexists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

Note that the `shtname` variable in the `sheetexists` is changed to a variant here.

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow the below Neat and clean Code to check to add sheets if don't exist. Else do Nothing. Easy to refactorable and Manageable if more sheets are added.**

```
Option Explicit

Public wb As Workbook
Public ws As Worksheet

'Declare the sheets in this array you want to add
Function sheetNamesArray() As Variant
    sheetNamesArray = Array("Square", "Circle", "Rectangle", "Hexagon")
End Function

' Function returns True, if sheet exist else returns False
Function isSheetExist(sSheet As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    isSheetExist = (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sSheet).Index > 0)
End Function


'Function to Create a Sheet in workbook with given name
Sub CreateSheet(sheetName As Variant)
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
    End With
    
End Sub

'Function to addSheets if doesn't exist, else do nothing
Sub Main()
    Dim asheet As Variant
    For Each asheet In sheetNamesArray
            If Not isSheetExist(CStr(asheet)) Then
                Call CreateSheet(asheet)
            End If
    Next asheet
End Sub
```

Comment: You can join this group to share your problems too.    https://www.facebook.com/groups/161963304594432